# Is It Possible For Parent And Child Views To Reference Each Other By Injection/Find Before Init Finishes?

Tags: tornadofx

I want an embedded view to be able to call a function from the parent view, so I'm trying to have the child reference its parent by injection. This seems to work fine as long as the embedded view is created onDock:

```
class TestView : View() {
    override val root = vbox {
        label("Parent Label")
    }

    init {
        println("Parent is instantiating.")
    }

    override fun onDock() {
        val child = find(TestView2::class)
        root.add(child)
    }

    fun doThing() {
        println("Parent is doing a thing.")
    }
}

class TestView2 : View() {
    val parentClass: TestView by inject()

    override val root = hbox {
        label("Sub-view label 1")
        label("Sub-view label 2")
    }

    init {
        println("Sub-view is instantiating.")
        parentClass.doThing()
    }
}
```

I'd like it to be cleaner though. I'd prefer it if I was able to use the find function while creating the parent root. That's a problem, as calling the child view within any part of the init process creates a circular instantiation loop. Any way to avoid this or will I just have to settle for onDock and deal with it?

**EDIT:**

Just to note, I tried the onDock method again in a real, more complicated application and I got a cycle detection error. So even that method is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create cyclic dependencies, but you can't call functions in both component's init block, as that would be impossible to resolve. The main takeaway here is that you're probably doing something you shouldn't. Views should not communicate with each other directly. This creates a tight coupling and prevents reuse. Instead you should communicate with one of the following:

1. State from a ViewModel
2. Controller function calls
3. Events using the EventBus

Since your code example is made up, it's not known what exactly you're trying to achieve in your actual app, but you will find the correct approach in the list above.

I see the urge to call functions in views and setting data directly into ui components instead of using bindings a lot, and in absolutely every case there is a much better way to solve the problem :)

Comment: Yes, this problem led me to using the EventBus, it's been helpful in decoupling! Now my sub-views/fragments get their info from an injected ViewModel and send out requests/info by event bus or calls to an injected controller (although I might try to decouple further and have my controllers and views only communicate with the event bus as well)